# upload image with laravel using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have table user:

- id (int)
- firstname (string)
- lastName (string)
- email (string)
- login (string)
- password (string)
- image (text)

I would like to insert image in my database using ajax jquery.

But at the given database level it does not insert the data with the image.

I try with this code but doesn't work.

**Controller**:

```
 public function addUser(Request $request){
        $user = new User();
        $user->lastName = $request->lastName;
        $user->firstName = $request->firstName;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->login = $request->login;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);

        if($request->has('image') ) {
                $file_local =  $request->file('image');
                $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                if($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'png' || $extension == 'jpeg'){
                  $name=$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
                  $path = $file_local->storeAS('public/',$name);

                   $user->image = $name;
              }   
          }
        $user->save();

        return response()->json($user);   
    }
```

**View**:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="last Name" required />

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="name" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="login" class="form-control" placeholder="Login" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <input type="file" id="image" class="form-control"  required  />
            </div>
</form>
```

**ajax**:

```
$(document).on('click', "#creer_utilisateur", function() {
    var lastName= $('#lastName').val();
    var firstName = $('#firstName').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var login = $('#login').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    var image = $('#image').val();

        success: function(data) {
            $.ajax({
              url: "{{action('UserController@addUser')}}",
              method: 'POST',
              data: {
                lastName: lastName,
                firstName: firstName,
                email: email,
                login: login,
                password: password,
                image: image
              },
              success: function(data) {
              alert('success');

              },
              error: function(){
                alert('failed');
              }
            });
        }
      });
  });
```

Comment: What is storing to your database right now? Are the files writing to the directory?

Comment: @dprogramz , no, there is no record in the database it always shows me alert ('failed')

Comment: hmm, could you post your User() class? maybe the problem is there

Answer (score 0):

You are actually saving the name of the image:

`$name=$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();`

...

`$user->image = $name;`

You said:

> "But at the given database level it does not insert the data with the image."

And the type of the column is:

`image (text)`

So, I guess you don't want to store the name, right?

Comment: I would like to store the URL of the image

Answer (score 0):

when you are using ajax to upload file you need to create form with File attribute. and Then append other values with that.

Something like this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
if ($('#images')[0].files.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $('#images')[0].files.length; i++)
        formData.append('file[]', $('#images')[0].files[i]);
}

formData.append('lastName', $('#lastName').val());
```

second when you pass files with ajax make sure cache is false.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "JSON",
    url: jQuery('form').attr('action'),
    xhr: function() {
        myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        return myXhr;
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        // Success
    },
    error: function(error) {
        // error
    },
});
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

---

you can change an image text area like you can select an image: file then you can insert a file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).